# Spring boot interface returns different types of data，How do I receive in front-end

Tags: javascript, spring, spring-boot, frontend, thymeleaf

Springboot has an interface, as follows

```
@PostMapping(value = "product/send")
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity send(@RequestBody AjaxRequest ajaxRequest) {
    return service.send(ajaxRequest);
}
```

This interface may return a picture, a String, or other types data. I want to show the interface result in the front-end. What should I do?
I use thymeleaf, other template implementation can also be. Who can help me? Thank you

Comment: You should be aware of the contract, what you receive in the front-end side to display. just like method produces something

Comment: I use the String type to receive at the front end. So when the return is a picture, a bunch of strings are displayed instead of the picture.